# Need help creating new column within csv file

Tags: linux, csv, awk, sed

I need to manipulate the file below to move anything with a leading "space" to a column of its own and populating the new column one with the data without a leading space.  I would like to do this through automation within Linux

```
Example01  
   xx:yy:zz:0f:9a:00  
   xx:yy:zz:0f:9a:0a  
   xx:yy:zz:0f:9a:0b  
   xx:yy:zz:0f:9a:0c  
   xx:yy:zz:0f:9a:0d  
   xx:yy:zz:0f:9a:0e

Example02  
   aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0a  
   aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0b  
   aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0c  
   aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0d  

Example03  
   aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0a  
   aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0b  
   aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0c  
   aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0d  

Example04  
   aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0a  
   aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0b  
   aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0c  
   aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0d
```

This is an example of desired output:

```
Example01    
Example01   xx:yy:zz:0f:9a:00  
Example01   xx:yy:zz:0f:9a:0a  
Example01   xx:yy:zz:0f:9a:0b  
Example01   xx:yy:zz:0f:9a:0c  
Example01   xx:yy:zz:0f:9a:0d  
Example01   xx:yy:zz:0f:9a:0e  

Example02  
Example02   aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0a  
Example02   aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0b  
Example02   aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0c  
Example02   aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0d  

Example03  
Example03   aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0a  
Example03   aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0b  
Example03   aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0c  
Example03   aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0d  

Example04  
Example04   aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0a  
Example04   aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0b  
Example04   aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0c  
Example04   aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0d
```

Comment: "I need help" is not a very helpful question. What have you tried and what specific problem did you encounter that you are asking help for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '{ if ($0 !~ /^ +/) a = $0;} {if (a != $0)  print a , " " , $0; else  print $0;}'
```

Demo:

```
renegade@Renegade:~$ cat test.txt
Example01  
   xx:yy:zz:0f:9a:00  
   xx:yy:zz:0f:9a:0a  
   xx:yy:zz:0f:9a:0b  
   xx:yy:zz:0f:9a:0c  
   xx:yy:zz:0f:9a:0d  
   xx:yy:zz:0f:9a:0e

Example02  
   aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0a  
   aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0b  
   aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0c  
   aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0d  

Example03  
   aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0a  
   aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0b  
   aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0c  
   aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0d  

Example04  
   aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0a  
   aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0b  
   aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0c  
   aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0d 
renegade@Renegade:~$ awk '{ if ($0 !~ /^ +/) a = $0;} {if (a != $0)  print a , " " , $0; else  print $0;}'  test.txt
Example01  
Example01        xx:yy:zz:0f:9a:00  
Example01        xx:yy:zz:0f:9a:0a  
Example01        xx:yy:zz:0f:9a:0b  
Example01        xx:yy:zz:0f:9a:0c  
Example01        xx:yy:zz:0f:9a:0d  
Example01        xx:yy:zz:0f:9a:0e

Example02  
Example02        aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0a  
Example02        aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0b  
Example02        aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0c  
Example02        aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0d  

Example03  
Example03        aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0a  
Example03        aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0b  
Example03        aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0c  
Example03        aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0d  

Example04  
Example04        aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0a  
Example04        aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0b  
Example04        aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0c  
Example04        aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0d
```

Comment: This solution worked perfectly.  Sorry for the lack of information.  Programming is not my forte but being a network engineer, I need to learn it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '!NF {print; next} /^[^ ]/ {print; hdr = $0} /^ / {print hdr, $0}' file
Example01
Example01    xx:yy:zz:0f:9a:00
Example01    xx:yy:zz:0f:9a:0a
Example01    xx:yy:zz:0f:9a:0b
Example01    xx:yy:zz:0f:9a:0c
Example01    xx:yy:zz:0f:9a:0d
Example01    xx:yy:zz:0f:9a:0e

Example02
Example02    aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0a
Example02    aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0b
Example02    aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0c
Example02    aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0d

Example03
Example03    aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0a
Example03    aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0b
Example03    aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0c
Example03    aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0d

Example04
Example04    aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0a
Example04    aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0b
Example04    aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0c
Example04    aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0d
```

**Explanation**

```
!NF {print; next}
```

On empty input lines, print an empty line and move on immediately to the next line of input

```
/^[^ ]/ {print; hdr = $0}
```

For lines that don't start with a space, print the line and save it as `hdr`

```
/^ / {print hdr, $0}'
```

For lines that do start with a space, print the saved `hdr` and the line

Comment: Why not `/^[ ]/ {print hdr, $1}` to eliminate the excess whitespace?

Comment: Yes, good point, @DavidC.Rankin. For one, the given desired ouput included the extra space. I also didn't know whether to count on there only being one field on the space-starting lines. Probably I should have clarified those two things with OP beforehand.

Comment: I wasn't sure which way it was wanted, but saw that as another option if some of the space needed to be trimmed. Good approach either way. (the file posted by the OP also has 2 extra spaces after the header which are picked up as well -- which adds and extra two to begin with, using `$1` could trim as well)

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
$ cat file
Example01  
    xx:yy:zz:0f:9a:00  
    xx:yy:zz:0f:9a:0a  
    xx:yy:zz:0f:9a:0b  
    xx:yy:zz:0f:9a:0c  
    xx:yy:zz:0f:9a:0d  
    xx:yy:zz:0f:9a:0e

Example02  
    aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0a  
    aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0b  
    aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0c  
    aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0d  

Example03  
    aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0a  
    aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0b  
    aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0c  
    aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0d  

Example04  
    aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0a  
    aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0b  
    aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0c  
    aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0d
```

You can `awk` this:

```
$ awk ' {if (NF==0) {if (s) print s; tag=s=""; next}}
        /^[^[:space:]]/{tag=$0; s=tag "\n"; next} 
        {s=s tag $1 "\n"'} file
Example01  
Example01  xx:yy:zz:0f:9a:00
Example01  xx:yy:zz:0f:9a:0a
Example01  xx:yy:zz:0f:9a:0b
Example01  xx:yy:zz:0f:9a:0c
Example01  xx:yy:zz:0f:9a:0d
Example01  xx:yy:zz:0f:9a:0e

Example02  
Example02  aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0a
Example02  aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0b
Example02  aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0c
Example02  aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0d

Example03  
Example03  aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0a
Example03  aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0b
Example03  aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0c
Example03  aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0d

Example04  
Example04  aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0a
Example04  aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0b
Example04  aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0c
Example04  aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0d
```

Comment: I'm not getting this output with this code (no "Example04" block and no space between the tags and the `$1` values). Did you paste different code than your final version?

Comment: Likely that is because there is not a terminating `\n` in the source given. Recall that a Posix file is considered 'broken' without the terminating `\n`. That said, it is not uncommon. Can be fixed with removing the prints in the body and having an `END {print s}`. Makes your version somewhat better `;-)`

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '{sub(/\r$/,"")} /^[^ ]/{hdr=$0; print; next} {print (NF ? hdr : "") $0}' file
Example01
Example01     xx:yy:zz:0f:9a:00
Example01     xx:yy:zz:0f:9a:0a
Example01     xx:yy:zz:0f:9a:0b
Example01     xx:yy:zz:0f:9a:0c
Example01     xx:yy:zz:0f:9a:0d
Example01     xx:yy:zz:0f:9a:0e

Example02
Example02     aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0a
Example02     aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0b
Example02     aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0c
Example02     aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0d

Example03
Example03     aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0a
Example03     aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0b
Example03     aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0c
Example03     aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0d

Example04
Example04     aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0a
Example04     aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0b
Example04     aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0c
Example04     aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0d
```

The `{sub(/\r$/,"")}` is because your posted sample input file has DOS line endings.

Answer (score 1):

Sed solution, which tolerates DOS `\r\n` line endings but will not use them in the output.

`sed -n '/^ /!{h;p};//{x;G;s/\r*\n//p;s/ .*//;h}' file`

This does:

- `sed -n` to not print without a `p`
- For lines not beginning with a space `/^ /!`:

  - `h` to hold the line
  - `p` to print it
- For lines beginning with a space `//` (uses previous match as pattern)

  - `x` to swap it into the hold space
  - `G` to append it onto the line that was in the hold space
  - `s/\r*\n//p` to remove dos/unix line break and print
  - `s/ .*//` to remove the appended line
  - `h` to return the non-space line back to the hold space

Comment: Good use of `sed`. Only though it that `"Example01   "` has a couple of spaces after it, so your fist output has a few additional spaces. Other than that. works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I like the solution by @jas, and building upon it, to generalize slightly, not knowing the type of *whitespace* used in the original file, you can make use of the regex patterns for `\s` (whitespace) and `\S` (non-whitespace) to include handling for both `space` and `tab` characters.

The other twist would be using the default field-separator (`FS`) and then use the first-field (`$1`) from the record to set the header and data-fields rather than using the entire records itself (`$0`). This has the benefit of removing any stray whitespace surrounding the field in the record giving you control over the spacing between the combined header and data.

Putting those together, you could write your expression as:

```
awk '!NF {print; next} /^\S/ {print $1; hdr=$1} /^\s/ {print hdr"  "$1}' file
```

or

```
awk '!NF {print; next} /^\S/ {print $1; hdr=$1; next} {print hdr"  "$1}' file
```

(`next` is included in the second rule to eliminating the need for the `/^\s/` test in the third rule, though I doubt that would provide much improvement in efficiency)

**Example Use/Output**

Setting the spacing between the header and data in the new rows as 2-spaces and noting the use of string-concatenation for the output, you would get:

```
$ awk '!NF {print; next} /^\S/ {print $1; hdr=$1; next} {print hdr"  "$1}' file
Example01
Example01  xx:yy:zz:0f:9a:00
Example01  xx:yy:zz:0f:9a:0a
Example01  xx:yy:zz:0f:9a:0b
Example01  xx:yy:zz:0f:9a:0c
Example01  xx:yy:zz:0f:9a:0d
Example01  xx:yy:zz:0f:9a:0e

Example02
Example02  aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0a
Example02  aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0b
Example02  aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0c
Example02  aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0d

Example03
Example03  aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0a
Example03  aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0b
Example03  aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0c
Example03  aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0d

Example04
Example04  aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0a
Example04  aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0b
Example04  aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0c
Example04  aa:bb:cc:ab:99:0d
```

Let me know if you have any questions and remember, credit for the base of this approach goes to @jas.